# In java I want to jump from a particular block of Statements to another block of statements. How can I achieve it?

Tags: java

```
public class abc{
    public static void main(){
       try{
               int a =10;
               if(a=10){
               throw new Exception();
       }
               l1:System.out.println(a);
       }catch(Exception e){
               continue l1;
       }
    }
}
```

Actually what I am trying to do is when an exception occurs I wish to continue the next statement after that as well.
Is there any way I can achieve it with Java?

Comment: Use `finally` to execute statements whether or not exception was thrown

Comment: When you say "I wish to continue the ne statement", do you mean "l1:System.out.println(a);"? If yes, finally statement could solve this.

Comment: are you looking for `finally` block?

Comment: did you try finally.. That would server you purpose

Comment: If not, you still can use flags ;)

Comment: You can comfortably live without continue/break labels in java, please try avoiding them, not a good practice to use them.

Comment: Read this : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185944/java-labels-to-be-or-not-to-be

Answer (score 0):

You would just want to put `System.out.println(a);` in the catch block.

Putting it in a finally block would mean that it is executed even when an exception does not occur. The program only goes to the catch block when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like

```
int a =0;
 try{
           a =10;
               if(a=10){
               throw new Exception();
}
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //do nothing
        } finally {
             l1:System.out.println(a);
        }
```

Anyway in java avoid jumping

Comment: `a` is not in the scope of the `finally` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 9;
    try {
        if (a == 10) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // only if there is any exception
    } finally {
        System.out.println(a); // always print this message
    }
}
```

Or if a is 10

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10;
    try {
        if (a == 10) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // only if there is any exception
    } finally {
        System.out.println(a); // always print this message
    }
}
```